# Proclaim method does not put a "!" behind each element

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote the following "proclaim method". It aims to take elements from a Array and put an "!" behind.

```
class ArrayModifier
attr_accessor :userArray
def initialize(userArray)
    @userArray = userArray
end

def exclaim
    newArray = []
    userArray.each do |num|
        newArray << "#{num}!"           
    end
    newArray
end

end
```

When I run it on this array

```
a = ["Henk", "Marc"] I get 

=> ["Henk!", "Piet!"]
```

which looks good. I get an RSPec error though

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

```
expected: "Hey! ho! let's! go!"
 got: "Hey! ho! let's! go"
```

And there it seems that's not putting a '!' behind the last element... Any ideas on where this is coming from?

Comment: could you show us the test?

Comment: Hahaha take a look at [Array#collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect) since the documentation is exactly your use case.

Comment: There's a better way to express your `exclaim` method `array.map { |element| "#{element}!" }`. Your code should work, though. So something else is going on. Do show us the test as pointed out by @UriAgassi.

Comment: How is the expectation a string when the method is returning an array? What is your test?

Comment: @UriAgassi, thanks for the reply, how do I show you the test? Kind of a newbe sorry :)

Comment: The test is the code which tells rspec what to check. It is the code which fails. It may have a line which looks something like this: `expect(result).to eql "Hey! ho! let's! go!"`

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you are splitting a line with a terminating newline character on the last `'go'`. Apply [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) to the line before splitting.

As a side note, you can simplify your `exclaim` method using [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
def exclaim
  userArray.map { |num| "#{num}!" }
end
```

Comment: Even if the input was `["Hey", "ho", "let's", "go\n"]` the output would have been `["Hey!", "ho!", "let's!", "go\n!"]`, not `["Hey!", "ho!", "let's!", "go"]`...

Comment: @UriAgassi It seems he is comparing a string rather than an array, so he is doing some post-processing, as questioned by Humza. Perhaps the post-processing is somehow involved with the dropping of the '!' after the newline. But thank you for the downvote in any case.